# Javascript array always undefine

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying push some values to javascript array, but I always have array of undefined values.

```
    var picArray = [];
    var picTmp;
    for(var i =0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        html2canvas($("#graph-"+i), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                picTmp = canvas.toDataURL();
            }
        });
        picArray.push(picTmp);
    }
    console.log(picArray);
```

All views are rendered. What's am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the magic number 4? Why numbered ids and not a common class? I would suggest refactoring the code to read more clearly, the solution you seek might not be the best solution.

Comment: Not sure what `html2canvas` is, but it would be async so `picArray.push(picTmp);` would be adding the value of `picTmp` before its been assigned in the above function. Move `picArray.push(picTmp);` to immediately after `picTmp = canvas.toDataURL();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your plugin is working `asynchronously`, so fill the array after your onrendered callback like,

```
html2canvas($("#graph-"+i), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
       picTmp = canvas.toDataURL();
       picArray.push(picTmp); // add here after render callback
   }
});
```